# How to put results of loop into a list?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, pivot

I have a dataset:

```
   a        b      c
11/01/1999  8   367235
11/01/1999  5   419895
11/01/1999  1   992194
23/03/1999  4   419895
30/04/1999  1   992194
02/06/1999  9   419895
08/08/1999  2   367235
12/08/1999  3   419895
17/08/1999  10  992194
22/10/1999  3   419895
04/12/1999  4   992194
04/03/2000  2   367235
29/09/2000  9   367235
30/09/2000  9   367235
```

I am trying to make a visualization that shows sets of values (column "b") changing over time (column "a"):

[image]

*please note, this is just to paint a general picture of what I'm going for - it is not my dataset.

I changed the dataset to a pivot table, which lists column "c" values in the first column, "a" values along the top row, and "b" values within the dataframe.  Happily, I have been able to extract the rows of values from the pivot table, and use this as the input to a matplotlib plot (representing the y values on my chart).  Unhappily, I cannot extract the header of the pivot table in an acceptable format, which is a problem because the header represents the x values on my chart.

Here's the part of the code that works:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = (pd.read_csv('orcs.csv'))
df_wanted = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index='c',
    columns='a',
    values='b')
lala = df_wanted.as_matrix()
x=np.array(lala[1,:])
y = (df_wanted.columns.astype(str).tolist())
```

Here is the part of the code that doesn't work.

I tried several alternatives (error messages included):

1.

```
plt.plot(x,y)# error: could not convert string to float: '02/06/1999'
```

2.

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    c= (y[i])
    print(c) #no error message, but gives me an output I don't know how to capture for the plt.plot input.
```

3.

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    c= (y[i])
    f = datetime.strptime(c, '%d/%m/%Y')
    v=list(f)
    plot.plot(x,v) # error message:'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to swap `index` and `columns` and then convert `index` to `datetime`. Then just `.plot()`.

```
df_wanted = pd.pivot_table(df, columns='c',
                           index='a', values='b')    
df_wanted.index = pd.to_datetime(df_wanted.index)
df_wanted.plot()
```

[image: The picture obtained]

Comment: llya V. Schurov, thank you very, very much for such an elegant solution.  You also saved me from having to write the code to deal with my 40,000 y-value rows.  I've been trying to do this for a while so I am very relieved it works.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `matplotlib.pyplot` for plotting then you can only specify numerical coordinates (i.e. non-string). But you can assign `str` labels to these coordinates

so you may want to consider this kind of code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime

yValues = [10,15,8,7,1]
xLabels = ['a', datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%M-%d"), 
                    'b', 'c', 'd']

fig = plt.figure()     
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7])
ax.plot(yValues)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(yValues)))
ax.set_xticklabels(xLabels, rotation = 'vertical')
fig.show()
```